# Form submission and passing parameters via URL

Tags: jsp, jsf

I have a Window where user can search for all the cars in the database and able to edit the details of the car, when user click the edit button (code below) on a given car the following JavaScript is called to open a New window:

```
  <!--EDIT BUTTON -->  
  <h:commandLink value=""
        onclick="return CarEditCrud(this);" title="Edit Car">
        <t:graphicImage rendered="true" value="/imgs/edit.gif"
            styleClass="edit" />
        <f:param value="#{car.carPK}" name="carCode" />
    </h:commandLink>

 <!--FUNCTION TO OPEN NEW WINDOW TO EDIT CAR DETAIL -->  
 function CarEditCrud(val) {   
 ....    
 window.open("EditCarCrud.faces?carPK=" + pk);
 }
```

So new window open with URL of `localhost:80/jsp/EditCarCrud.faces?carPK=" + pk` (NOTE: PK would be a number like 935533)
and in constructor of EditCarCrud Backbean i do the following to retrieve the information of the car and populate the fields:

```
Map requestMap = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();
String code = (String) requestMap.get("carCode");
```

That's all good. Problem is this Backbean has `Request` scope when user press Submit, i lose all that information (carCode) so the URL is now `localhost:80/jsp/EditCarCrud.faces`.

### UPDATE:

Additionally, there is `selectOneItem` which has

```
  ....
  valueChangeListener="#{carEditCurd.countrycodechange}"
  onchange="submit()"
```

Is there a way for me to keep the carCode in the URL as it was when window originally opened  with the PK in the URL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that you're still using JSF 1.x.

You need to retain the request parameter in the subsequent forms by `<f:param>`:

```
<h:commandLink value="Submit" ...>
    <f:param name="carCode" value="#{param.carCode}" />
</h:commandLink>
```

This does not end up in the URL, but it is available as POST request parameter the usual way. The `<managed-property>` is by the way a more clean way to let JSF set arbitrary request parameters as bean properties.

An alternative is to add a plain HTML `<input type="hidden">` to the form, so that it also get submitted when a dropdown with `onchange="submit()"` inside the same form get changed:

```
<input type="hidden" name="carCode" value="<h:outputText value="#{param.carCode}" />" />
```

*(yes, with an ugly `<h:outputText>` nested as value, it's just to prevent possible XSS attacks)*

Note that a `<h:inputHidden>` is not useable as it loses its value when validation on the form fails.

Comment: You're right, this is all JSF 1.x. I'm trying your Suggestion right now - ON the same page (`CarEditCrud`) there is a SelectOneItem with ValueChangeListener and `onchange=submit()`. The dropdown is associated with country, so when user changes the dropdown the form is submitted which means i lose the information `carCode`. How can i retain the Request Parameter when submit is called by dropdown?

Comment: Yes Yes Yes, I love you #BalusC.